# 404 Error report getting refreshed?

Tags: 7, log-messages

For some reason CRON seems to be deleting all 404 errors reported at

```
admin/reports/page-not-found
```

Is there any way to disable the deleting of the 404 errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watchdog entries are deleted by [`dblog_cron()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!dblog!dblog.module/function/dblog_cron/7.x), if the `dblog_row_limit` variable is greater than 0.

To stop them being deleted, set the `dblog_row_limit` variable to `0`.

Comment: I didn't realise these are considered watchdog entries.